# Rendering many highcharts is very slow, can I make it non blocking

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have around 300 highcharts on one page. After loading of the html and data, the rendering of highcharts is taking around 3 seconds. I made two functions which take a few parameters(div to be rendered to and data ) which in turn uses Highcharts.Chart() function to reder the chart. I am calling those functions multiple times to render charts in divisions. Here  is how the code looks like :

```js
    for(i=0;i<json_object.length;i++)
    {
        var container= document.getElementById("q_"+json_object[i].q_no);
        distribution_chart(container, json_object[i]['distribution_texts'],json_object[i]['distribution_values']);
        for (j=0;j<json_object[i]['meta_distributions'].length;j++)
        {
            var container= document.getElementById("q_"+json_object[i].q_no+"_"+j);
            for (k=0; k< json_object[i]['meta_distributions'][j]['distribution_values'].length;k++)
            {
                json_object[i]['meta_distributions'][j]['distribution_values'][k]=parseFloat(json_object[i]['meta_distributions'][j]['distribution_values'][k])
            }
            distribution_chart_demographic(container,json_object[i]['meta_distributions'][j]['distribution_texts'],json_object[i]['meta_distributions'][j]['distribution_values'],json_object[i]['meta_distributions'][j]['distribution_values_pos']);
        }

    }
```

Can i render the highcharts in a non blocking way. Or such that the first few highcharts render during the page load and the others keep rendering in the background after that.

Comment: Could you link this to a jsfiddle please?

Comment: There is no way to ever render them in a completely non-blocking way. You are always going to block whilst rendering each chart. However, you can be smarter about when you choose to render them. For example, are all charts visible on the page when it loads? If not, you could create/render each one as it becomes visible. Otherwise, you could schedule each chart to render after a short delay to allow other code to run.

Comment: I too like to view 300 different charts on a single page.

Comment: Also, your code would be easier to read if you assigned local variables to refer to each element in the array, so instead of `json_object[i]['meta_distributions'][j]` you just had `meta_dist` or similar. You should also be able to use [`.forEach(function (elementVar) { ... })`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of the `for` loop to simplify this if you don't need to support anything older than IE9.

Comment: Maybe better is load chart which are "in visible" part of page and then catch scroll event and load "dynamically" other charts?